# Magento2 Luma move category image so its full width

Tags: magento2.2, layout

In my magento 2.2 based site I am trying to edit the catalog_category_view.xml to move the category image above the page-main div and after the breadcrumbs so that it will load full width (in the Luma theme)

I tried the below inside the body tag in the xml but that does not work it seems to put it after the footer on bottom of page.

my xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="columns.top">
        <container name="category.view.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="category-view" after="-">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.image" template="Magento_Catalog::category/image.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.description" template="Magento_Catalog::category/description.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.cms" template="Magento_Catalog::category/cms.phtml"/>
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.products" template="Magento_Catalog::category/products.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
                <container name="category.product.list.additional" as="additional" />
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers" as="details.renderers">
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="category.product.type.details.renderers.default" as="default"/>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="category.product.addto" as="addto">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                           name="category.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                           template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                </block>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                    <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
                </action>
            </block>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="compareProductLink" xsi:type="string">.action.tocompare</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">page-title-heading</argument>
            <argument name="add_base_attribute_aria" xsi:type="string">page-title-heading toolbar-amount</argument>
        </arguments>
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\Rss\Link" name="rss.link" template="Magento_Catalog::category/rss.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
    <move element="category.image" destination="breadcrumbs" after="-"/>
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="view.addto.compare" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="view.addto.wishlist" remove="true" />
</body>
```

Suggestions on what the move tag should be. also just for my understanding the "element" is the css class name of the element I want to move, the before is the css class name of what element i want to load it before and the destination would be the css class name of the div the content should be in or moved into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this one:

```
<move element="category.image" destination="page.wrapper" before="main.content" />
```

After update this run:

> php bin/magento cache:clean

Comment: Thank you @Ravi now the image doesnt load at all. However i pasted my entire xml so you can see it

Comment: Okay, Let me check

Comment: Please check now. I have updated my answer.

Comment: that worked thanks @Ravi

Comment: Thanks for mark as right answer.. :)